# How to mock Blob and Click() in jasmine Specs in angular js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, specs

How to write Jasmine specs for Blob and Click() event. Every time I am running Specs its downloading file. Can I mock this (and browser also).

Thanks

```
var csvFile = "a,b,c",filename="abc.csv";

var blob = new Blob([csvFile], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                link.setAttribute("download", filename);
                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        }


describe("Should check download CSV", function() {
  it("file name should be 7 char", function() {
    expect(filename.length).toBe(7);
  });
});

});
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: You found any solution to this? Similar problems we are having in 2018